# Backspace and arrow keys freeze when hitting MaxLength in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, maxlength

Why do the navigation (arrow) keys and the backspace become frozen when the number of characters entered in the multiline textbox becomes equal to the MaxLength set?
What is its solution ?

Comment: increase the `MaxLength` property :P

Comment: Very funny :P still the keys will get locked up on reaching the maxlength

Comment: Do you have any associated events with textbox? Any part of your code modifies its attributes?

Comment: no there are no associated events. neither i can see any code modifying its attributes

Comment: Is the textbox hanging up alone or all the UI elements?

Comment: only that textbox where the characters are equal to the MaxLength , no issues with the rest of the UI. it works nicely till the characters enetered are Maxlenth-1, as soon as you type the next one the backspace,navigation arrows freez

Comment: hmmm... this is strange. What is .net verion you are using? Before I say it is a bug, I suggest searching for all usages of that textbox in your code (with visual studio tool). There can be some infinite loop or a bug up or down.

Comment: The version is 4.0 , i have encountered this sort of thing before also but i dont know how that team fixed it